# Racket/Scheme embed list within existing list

Tags: racket

I'm attempting to embed a list in to an existing list, the problem is explained below.

list1

```
bla
bla
bla
bla
```

list2

```
useful stuff
is here
```

while my function iterates list1 it picks a random point where it will then insert:

```
useful stuff
is here
```

the issue is that list2 now looks like:

```
bla
bla
useful stuff is here
bla
bla
```

instead of:

```
bla
bla
useful stuff 
is here
bla
bla
```

I'm totally confused, I've googled and read the documentation but I just can not find an answer, everything I have tried has failed.

Comment: A list in `#!racket` (and Scheme) looks like this: `(element aonother-element ...)`. Also you better show your code since it's impossible for us to know if `useful stuff is here` is a printed string, list of symbols or pehaps something entirely different.

Comment: there is no code, nothing has worked so i just try and then delete, my post explains what i'm trying to do. Simply embedding one list in to another without list2 being flat.

Comment: The question is Greek to me. You need to edit in the parentheses and what you have tried. I fear you won't get any answers without changing it to something meaningful to racketeers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#lang racket
(define list1 '("bla" "bla" "bla" "bla"))
(define list2 '("useful stuff" "is here"))

(define insertion-point (random (length list1)))

(append (take list1 insertion-point)
        list2
        (drop list1 insertion-point))
```

The result on the first run:

```
'("bla" "useful stuff" "is here" "bla" "bla" "bla")
```

Comment: thank you that was great, had the read the documentation on the functions you used, modified it a little but you saved me a lot of time! :D